# uploading an excel file using selenium doesn't work when running from jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have a test to upload an excel file using selenium , i'm using the following code:

```
String filePath = getLatestFile.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(filePath);
        StringSelection excel_file = new StringSelection(filePath);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(excel_file, null);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

when i run my test directly from a batch file everything work perfectly , but when i run it from jenkins it fail while pasting the filePath in upload form because it's not focused on it , any help concerning this problem?

Comment: what is the value that is getting assigned to the filePath variable? Is that Excel file available in that location for Jenkins slave machine?

Comment: filePath variable is equal the full path of the excel file , and yes it's available in that location

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the error or info with us but their are so much reasons that the file cannot written

1. The file should exists in the directory that you are passing
2. If the file exists it should be closed while you writing in that file
3. If file exists the name and the extension like .xsl, or .txt and so on..
4. If file exists the path you have given that should be the exact path where the file is reside.

   I think you can find solution on the basis of above details but please share console or log info with us so we can give you better answert

Comment: after uploading the excel file i'm checking the values if uploaded in the form , so the error appear on the assert condition that i use the problem in my opinion is that the upload form is not focused on it because if i press on it while test is running everything works okey , but i can't find a solution in selenium for this problem